# How to browse Added Data in Embedded H2 database

Tags: wso2, wso2-governance-registry

I used the out of box H2 embedded database for WSO2 Gov Registry 4.6.0 and added many entries there. I am trying to view the data in tables in the database but somehow cannot see the tables.

I logged in the embedded H2 database but only see the system tables and no tables or data that I added to the registry.

How can I get access to the REG_* and UM_* tables in the database to see the data?

I tried to see the tables in H2 db browser and DBVisualizer but cannot see tables and data in both.

Error log:

> [2014-11-22 16:32:57,972]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.h2.osgi.console.ConsoleService} -  Starting H2 Web
>   server... [2014-11-22 16:32:58,191]  INFO
>   {org.wso2.carbon.h2.osgi.console.ConsoleService} -  Starting H2 TCP
>   server... org.h2.server.TcpServerThread@65fe28a7 Connect [2014-11-22
>   16:32:58,193]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.h2.osgi.console.ConsoleService} -
>   Starting H2 PG server... Connect Disconnect Close
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake    at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkWrite(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppOutputStream.write(AppOutputStream.java:44)
>     at
>   java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
>     at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
>     at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)    at
>   org.h2.value.Transfer.flush(Transfer.java:85)     at
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.sendError(TcpServerThread.java:197)     at
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:129)   at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695) Caused by:
>   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Received close_notify during handshake    at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:190)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1747)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1703)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:1801)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1004)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1188)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:818)
>     at
>   com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
>     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)   at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:237)    at
>   java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:370)     at
>   org.h2.value.Transfer.readInt(Transfer.java:145)  at
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:71)    ... 1 more
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread@65fe28a7 Disconnect
>   org.h2.server.TcpServerThread@65fe28a7 Close

Answer (score 7):

All the WSO2 products are default shipped with H2 database.

This can be easily achieved by enabling the H2DatabaseConfiguration in carbon.xml.

1. Go to the CARBON_HOME/repository/config
2. Open the carbon.xml file.
3. Paste the H2DatabaseConfiguration as follows.(**don't uncomment the H2DatabaseConfiguration which already there** *just paste below code*)

> ```
> <H2DatabaseConfiguration>
>         <property name="web"/>
>         <property name="webPort">8082</property>
>         <property name="webAllowOthers"/>        
> </H2DatabaseConfiguration>
> ```

4. Start the the server.
5. Direct your browser to `http://localhost:8082`
6. Fill the JDBC URL, username and password as follows.

   - JDBC URL : jdbc:h2:/repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB
   - username : wso2carbon
   - password  : wso2carbon

Hope this helps!

Comment: One more tip for the connection, you can check the  ./distribution/src/repository/conf/datasources/master-datasources.xml file for the connection parameters, URL, username and password to the DB that you want to connect.

Comment: @zygimantus are you sure? Please refer the last screenshot. http://sencs.blogspot.sg/2014/11/how-to-browse-h2-database-in-wso2.html